# Days name in order in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array like

```
var abc = ["mon","Thu","Fri","Tue","Wed","Sun","Sat"]
```

So next I want these days in order like

```
["mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
```

Is there any inbuilt functions or any logic for it?

Comment: No, use a date object and then check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: arrays are in hard braces, not curly.

Comment: This is object not array.With your current input it is directly not possible to  build a logic.what did you attempt?

Comment: That is not an object. Anyway, what would be the point in ordering it programmatically when you already know the outcome? Just do `var abc = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"];`

Comment: @Navoneel  I was trying to use switch case statement for this... But it's a lengthy process...

Comment: @Vbranden Sorry just wrote it by mistake...

Answer (score 0):

I used a map object to be used along with a sort function .. pretty easy.

```
var arrayOfDays = ["Mon","Thu","Fri","Tue","Wed","Sun","Sat"];  //array to be sorted

//int this map, define the "correct" order of days
var map = {
           "Sun" : 0,
           "Mon" : 1,
           "Tue" : 2,
           "Wed" : 3,
           "Thu" : 4,
           "Fri" : 5,
           "Sat" : 6,
        }

function dateSort(array) //function to sort the array
{
    for(i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
        for(j = i + 1 ; j < array.length ; j++)
        {
            if(map[array[i]] > map[array[j]])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
}
```

It can be invoked as follows:

```
datesort(arrayOfDays);
```

I tested it by printing the values of array of dates before calling the function and after:

```
Before:   Mon Thu Fri Tue Wed Sun Sat

After:    Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
```

EDIT: As suggested by others, a version using Array.sort() - though avoid it if you are a beginner.

Define a custom compare function:

```
function dateCompare(d1, d2)
{
    if(map[d1] == map[d2])
        return 0;
    return (map[d1] < map[d2]) ? -1 : 1;

}
```

Invoke as:

```
arrayOfDays.sort(dateCompare);
```

Comment: Use the Array.sort function next time please. It looks better and abit more efficient

Comment: It cannot be done with plain Array.sort(). Please read the code carefully. The sorting algorithm compares each element with it's correct order in the map.. and not the actual element. It can be done by using a compare function, but the OP seems a beginner hence I avoided it in order to keep it simple.

Comment: @aditya_m: It can be done with Array.sort(comparefunction)

Comment: @aditya_m: Of course it *can* and should be done with `Array.sort`. You are passing in a callback, you can tell it exactly what to do. It's actually quite trivial: https://jsfiddle.net/0bcpkfd2/

Comment: I know that Array.sort is the best practice to do it. But OP hasn't yet learned the syntax of declaring an array, so I assumed that he/she is a beginner. Please read my edited comment.

Comment: Its ok if OP didnt know it, this is where you learn things, using code's best practices. As others said, it can easily be done with Array.Sort if comparing number value from the map object. In addition to guide the OP, its important that answer will be provided with a 'fine' code.

Comment: I wrote the answer as I saw fit. Due to request by many people, I edited it to include Arrays.sort. I hope you are okay with it. If not, please feel free to add an answer containing a code that matches your expectations.

Comment: @Vicky the strings can be converted to numbers and be sorted this way. Read previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by others, you need to use square brackets for arrays, not curly ones:

```
var abc = ["mon","Thu","Fri","Tue","Wed","Sun","Sat"];
```

There is no predefined method that recognizes weekdays, but you can just compare given day names to a list that is in the correct order, like this:

```
function compareDayNames(day1, day2) {
    var weekdays = ',monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday';
    return weekdays.indexOf(',' + day1.toLowerCase())
            - weekdays.indexOf(',' + day2.toLowerCase());
}

var abc = ["mon","Thu","Fri","Tue","Wed","Sun","Sat"];

abc.sort(compareDayNames);

console.log('Sorted: ' + abc.join(','));
```

Output in the console is:

```
Sorted: mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun
```

This function also sorts longer and shorter names well:

```
var abc = ['Satur','Tu', 'W', 'M', 'Thurs'];
abc.sort(compareDayNames);

console.log('Sorted: ' + abc.join(','));
```

Output:

```
Sorted: M,Tu,W,Thurs,Satur
```

EDIT:

If you want to throw an error when an invalid day name is provided, or a name that is less than 2 characters (because T and S are ambiguous), then rewrite the compare function as follows:

```
function compareDayNames(day1, day2) {
    var weekdays = ',monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday';

    function dayNumber(day) {
        var pos = weekdays.indexOf(',' + day.toLowerCase());
        if (pos === -1 || day.length < 2) {
            throw '"' + day + '" is not a valid day name';
        }
        return pos;
    }

    return dayNumber(day1) - dayNumber(day2);
}
```

Comment: Since you are using single character day names as well, what will be the output for `M W T S F T S`?

Comment: The output will be M,T,T,W,F,S,S. Of course, T and S are ambiguous, and are taken to be Tuesday and Saturday. Just don't use them like you would not use them in real life "I have an appointment on T" could lead to disappointments.

Comment: Right. Perhaps you could keep the minimum input length to 2 to avoid ambiguity. Then it would be a truly versatile function.

Comment: What would you want to happen when the input length is 1 of one or more values? Remove them from the array?

Comment: Of course not. The right way to handle it gracefully would be to throw an error...

Comment: I have added this now in my answer. The compare function will now throw an error in that case, and also when a completely invalid name is provided, like 'XXX'. If you find the answer satisfactory, please accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Great.. I would have accepted it, had I been the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function for it, you need to write your own logic as suggested in other answers. You can create one common function to compare two array's as...

```
function compareDays(wrongSquence , rightSequence) {
   var i=0;
   for(i=0;i<wrongSquence.length;i++) {
      if(wrongSquence [i] != rightSequence[i]) {       
          wrongSquence [i] = rightSequence[i];
      }
   } 
   return wrongSquence;
}

//e.g....
var abc = ["mon","Thu","Fri","Tue","Wed","Sun","Sat"],
outputFormat = ["mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"];

var correctArray = compareDays(abc, outputFormat);
console.log(correctArray);  // check output...
```

Comment: Try to format only code as code, not your whole post.

Comment: What if you call the function with fewer days, like ['Sat', 'Thu', 'Fri']? Should it not just sort them to ['Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']?

Comment: Yes , this function will sort them., for that you need to give two paramenter sas 
compareDays(['Sat', 'Thu', 'Fri'],['Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']);

Comment: What is the use of a function if you have to provide it the right answer in every call? You might as well do this then: `correct = abc.join(',') === 'Thu,Fri,Sat'`. No need for a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var ndays = "";
            var days = "Sat,Fri,mon,Thu,Tue,Wed,Sun";
            var dys = days.split(",");
            debugger;
            for (var i = 0; i < dys.length; i++) {
                switch (dys[i]) {
                    case "mon":
                        ndays = ndays + ",1";
                        break;
                    case "Tue":
                        ndays = ndays + ",2";
                        break;
                    case "Wed":
                        ndays = ndays + ",3";
                        break;
                    case "Thu":
                        ndays = ndays + ",4";
                        break;
                    case "Fri":
                        ndays = ndays + ",5";
                        break;
                    case "Sat":
                        ndays = ndays + ",6";
                        break;
                    default:
                        ndays = ndays + ",7";
                        break;
                }
                alert(ndays);
            }
            var cDays = "";

            var wdays = ndays.split(",").sort();

            for (var s = 0; s < wdays.length; s++) {
                //alert(wdays[s]);
                debugger;
                if (wdays[s] === "1") {
                    cDays = "Mon";
                }
                else if (wdays[s] === "2") {
                    cDays = cDays + ",Tue";
                }
                else if (wdays[s] === "3") {
                    cDays = cDays + ",Wed";
                }
                else if (wdays[s] === "4") {
                    cDays = cDays + ",Thu";
                }
                else if (wdays[s] === "5") {
                    cDays = cDays + ",Fri";
                }
                else if (wdays[s] === "6") {
                    cDays = cDays + ",Sat";
                }
                else {
                    cDays = cDays + ",Sun";
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should add some explaining text to the answer

Comment: You assigned number value to the string then you sorted it and you got the result.